# Is there a way to cancel Traffic Migration in Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I clicked the Migrate Traffic button in the App Engine console, and it seems to be stuck on "Traffic move is in progress.". According to the documentation it should only take a few minutes.

[image]

Looking at the log it seems the new version doesn't start up, because I accidentally compiled the app with Java 8, which App Engine does not support.
I am unable to upload the updated Java 7 compiled version. I get this error: 

`There is an operation pending for this application: AppLock held for "traffic migration in engine_id='default' from engine_version_id='1' to engine_version_id=u'2'" acquired by Unknown User at 2015-09-16 13:36:47.685270 GMT.  Please wait and try again or use 'appcfg rollback' to attempt to cleanly abort the current operation.
This is try #3` 
So App Engine has locked it because of the traffic migration.. 
App Engine lock keeps me from updating the "bad" version because of the traffic migration, while the traffic migration is stuck because of the "bad" version.

I tried uploading a 3rd version to see if that would change anything, but everything is still greyed out.

How do I cancel the traffic migration so I can get out of this situation?

Comment: Have you tried to use rollback?

Comment: Hi @Nick No I had not tried that. I never used any command line options before. But it worked! rollback seems to have released the lock, enabling me to deploy my java 1.7 compiled version. Can you change your comment to an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the solution was, as Nick suggested to do a 'rollback'. Had I read the error message I got more carefully I would have tried it sooner. Shame on me.

So how to do a rollback? I was not familiar with using the commandline to operate on a app-engine project. I have relied on the IDE tools to upload my app previously. I'll try to explain it here how I did it.

So the program to use is '**appcfg**'. It is located in the app-engine SDK directory under /bin. In my case `D:\Java\appengine-java-sdk-1.9.25\bin`

So the syntax would be `appcfg -rollback <root of *compiled* war folder>`

For example `appcfg -rollback D:\Projects\MyProject\out\artifacts\MyProject_war_exploded\` (I am using Intellij Idea, so if using other IDE your directory structure might be different)

A minute or less after doing this, the traffic migration completed successfully.

Hope this helps someone in the future!

Comment: Glad to hear it worked :) My answer came from reading the error message ;)